# DD-WRT PPTP VPN problem

Tags: networking, vpn, router, site-to-site-vpn, pptp-client

I try to configure a DD-WRT as a PPTP client. The VPN Server is Windows Server 2003.

This is my scenario:

[image: My Network]

The Windows 2003 Server has set to give to the VPN Client the 10.0.0.81 fixed IP and to add a network route to the remote home.

[image: VPN User]

At the remote home I have changed the PPTP Options at DD-WRT to make the connection.

[image: PPTP Client]

The VPN connection is successfully established.
[image: VPN Connection]

...and Windows successfully add the route to the remote home 192.168.2.X.

[image: Route Print]

From the remote home I can successfully access any computer from the VPN server side.

[image: Ping from 192.168.2.135 to 10.0.0.X]

The problem is when I try to access the remote home from the Server side.

[image: Ping from 10.0.0.X to 192.168.0.X]

From Server side I only can access\ping DD-WRT ( by VPN Client IP - 10.0.0.81).

[image: Ping VPN Client IP 10.0.0.81 from 10.0.0.X]

What's wrong?

How I need to do to be a site-to-site VPN?

This is what happen when I try to tracert the remote home from local home.

[image: Tracert 192.168.2.2]

Comment: Just a side note; the security of PPTP is a debatable topic. If your remote ends have static IPs set up IPSEC, or use OpenVPN, dymanic and more secure than PPTP.

Answer (score 0):

What services are you trying to access on the Home PPTP Client? It looks like to my you are trying to connect through windows explorer over samba or port 445. I think you need to open up your Windows Firewall on the home computer.

Comment: No. I need to access everything (files, VoIP, computers, printers). I don´t use Samba. And, I can access everything at the Home Computer Network. The problem is just when I try access the remote home (behind DD-WRT client) from the local home.

Comment: I upload new image from tracert remote home from local home.

Comment: Can you try to turn off your Windows firewall on the home computer and try again?

Comment: Sorry about the delay, i don´t receive the e-mail with answer update. Windows Firewall is already disabled. If i connect directly from one computer to VPN I can ping both sides. The problem is only with the router.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this answer as it is now well over a year after this question was posted.  Extensive security testing has been performed on Microsoft's PPTP implementation and it was determined that the [protocol is relatively insecure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pptp#Security).

The DD-WRT group strongly recommends using the OpenVPN capabilities of the system for stronger security and authentication.